# Reading Excel file using java program

Tags: java

I am reading a excel file using java and i am executing the program with the below command but its giving me error: `Could not find or load main class Test`

My main class is in the same directory where i am running the program `D:\java\Test>java -classpath "D:\java\Test\poi-3.9-20121203.jar;D:\java\Test\poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar Test`

Spent whole day to find out why this error is coming please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are two main causes:

The **first likely** cause is that you may have provided the wrong class name. (Or ... the right class name, but in the wrong form.)

The **second likely** cause is that the class name is correct, but that the java command cannot find the class. To understand this, you need to understand the concept of the **"classpath"**. This is explained well by the Oracle documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Setting classpath:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

The Java Tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

For more detail check this link
 [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)